# Broker Cost Historic extrapolation

Tags: transaction-costs

Given some broker costs today. What is the best way to extrapolate them into the history ? Would it be linear or exponential rise (towards history) ?

This would be for backtest simulation involving multi-asset class futures, to incorporate appropriate broker costs. Not looking for price impacts in transactions.

Comment: Sorry, but the question needs major clarification! What exactly is the data; and what exactly do you wish to infer from it?

Comment: Let me know if it helps better. Too much head in the problem made me miss it generalize/clarify enough.

Comment: So if I understood you would like to extrapolate broker commissions and exchange fees on Futures Trades backwards into the past. Say I pay 2.00 USD per round trip for buying/selling an S&P  emini contract today, how much would I have paid N years ago, this kind of thing?

Comment: If you have the data just visualize it.  You should be able to see whether the relationship is linear, exponential, logarithmic, quadratic, etc.  After you understand the high level relationships between your variables you can model it.